# MOODLE 2.6.3 Options aren't working

Tags: moodle

![enter image description here][1]I have installed MOODLE 2.6.3 successfully on LINUX machine. When I login as an admin, some of the links aren't working (ex: Appearance, Users, Courses, Edit Settings etc.,). Do we need to enable any option.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Links possibly aligned at the left side of the screen (vertically)? Or can you see them but can't use them?

Comment: Is your internet connection down? Parts of the resources (arrow images) linked incorrectly? I probably can't help you out any further.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm whether you are using the required PHP version. Moodle 2.6.3 requires PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Yes.. Iam using the required PHP version.. other else while installing MOODLE, it would had displayed an error, but the installation went successfully without any error

Comment: Turn on debugging and check the apache log. It may be a permission issue.

Comment: Tried on Debugging, no specific errors I could get.. Really not understanding why this links were not working.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an Ajax issue, the site admin menu works differently in 2.6+

If you go to /admin/settings.php?section=ajax

Tick the box for "Use online YUI libraries (useexternalyui)"

Then refresh the page.

UPDATE :

Okay after checking the use online YUI libraries, can you go to /admin/purgecaches.php and purge the caches.

If that doesn't work then try a different theme /theme/index.php and refresh.

Just found these options too :

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Blocks_FAQ#My_Administration_block_links_don.27t_expand.21

Comment: Thank You Russell England. I have enabled the option "Use online YUI libraries", but its happening the same, I couldn't open the links. Is there any other option to solve the issue.

Comment: "The links aren't working" Could you explain what isn't working? Are the menus displayed? Are they displayed but you can't click them? Or Something else?

Comment: Yes Russel..I could see the links, but no arrows and not able to open them

Comment: Thank You Russel..I will do check this option.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the errorlog file where you can find the errors or PHP warnings that is logged when loading the site. It may give you idea about the issue.

Comment: I don't find any error log, even If I am in Debugging mode

Comment: Generally, on all production web servers displaying error to end users via a web browser is turned off using php.ini file settings. Open /etc/php.ini file and find out line that read as follows: error_log                                                        The error_log directive defines the name of the file where script errors should be logged.  If the special value syslog is used, the errors are sent to the system logger instead.

Comment: Or <?php phpinfo(); ?> Error_Log section find the path. If you are using cPanel then it might probably be at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log